# Date range calculation for a project revenue in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date-range, revenue

I have a table `ClientProfile` that contains a column called `StartDate`, the datatype of this column is `date`, the second column is called `MonthlyRevenue` which is the amount column in `numeric(18,2)` and the third column is called `ContractMonths` datatype `int` which specifies the number of months the project will be active for. A user is required to select a date range and the query should be able to fetch the full date range (month wise) specifying the amount for each month.

For example:
Project A is going to start from `2020-03-01` (`1st March`) and the contract will run for 6 months so when a user selects dates `02-2020` to `12-2020`.

I should be able to get a result like this:

```
Month     Revenue
-----------------   
02-2020   0
03-2020   100
04-2020   100
05-2020   100
06-2020   100
07-2020   100
08-2020   100
09-2020   0
10-2020   0
11-2020   0
12-2020   0
```

I would really appreciate any help because I am stuck at this point and not able to figure this out.

Comment: Show us please what have you done so far ? Because "I'm stuck at this point and not able to figure this out". Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is a recursive CTE to generate the months:

```
with months as (
      select @startmonth as mon
      union all
      select dateadd(month, 1, mon)
      from months
      where mon < @endmonth
     )
select months.mon, coalesce(cp.monthlyrevenue, 0) as revenue
from months left join
     clientprofile cp
     on cp.project = @project and
        cp.startdate <= months.mon and
        dateadd(month, cp.contractmonths, cp.startdate) >= months.mon;
```

If the period can exceed 100 months, you need to add `option (maxrecursion 0)`.

Alternatively, you can build a monthly calendar table into your application and do pretty much he same thing using that table directly.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, thats exactly what I was looking for and it worked.